# PHP - ReflectionClass - getMethods only for current class

Tags: php

Currently I try to integrate PHPUnit in my project.
To ensure a 100% test coverage over time, I want to check if all methods that exist in the class to be tested in the testclass.
So I thought I could write something like

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private function _getClassFunctions($class) {
        $class = new ReflectionClass($class);
        return $class->getMethods();
    }

    public function testCompareFunctionCount() {
        $this->assertEquals($this->_getClassFunctions('MyClass'), $this->_getClassFunctions(__CLASS__));
    }
}
```

It seems, however, that ReflectionClass::getMethods() counts not only the methods of the class itself, but also all of the extended classes.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Or did I get something totally wrong? I read in older articles that ReflectionClass::getMethods() doesn't work correctly on older PHP-Versions, but I thought it might be fixed by now (those articles are 4+ years old...)

I use PHP 5.4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do some of the work yourself :

```php
private function _getClassFunctions($className) {
   $class = new ReflectionClass($className);
   $result = array();
   foreach($class->getMethods() as $method) {
      if ($method->class == $className) {
         $result[]=$method;
      }
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Comparing `$method->class` to `$className` narrow down the result to methods contained in the class in question only.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.
Thank you very much! :)